# What is a word for someone who has never attended a different school?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word or phrase to describe students at a K-12 school who have attended this same school the whole time from kindergarten through 12th grade. The first of these students will be graduating from our school soon, and referring to them as "long-term students" or "early adopters" doesn't work well to get the meaning across. Thank you for any help you can give.

Comment: You mean like how we call somebody who works for the same company for their entire working career a *lifer*?

Comment: I think you're talking about the school's inaugural class--the first students to enter the school.  Some have attended only this school.  Others may have attended and returned.  Some of them started with Kindergarten.  I know of no single word.

Comment: The first class to go *full spectrum* at the school.

Comment: Because you seem to keep some kids all the way up from kindergarten you might use tchrist's *lifer*.

Otherwise you might coin a term like uni-scholastic; uni-academic; uni-collegiate.

I think you're right about *long-term students* and *early adopters*, too.

Comment: "lifer" originates from prisoners with life sentences (mostly murderers, one assumes) and so I don't think it's a nice choice to describe school children.  It has connotations of school as being a prison.

Comment: @MaxWilliams, schools are basically little gulags or indoctrination camps, so _lifer_ works pretty well (apart from the fact that you get out at the end).

Comment: @dangph if that's your opinion, then I'm sorry school sucked so much for you!  I think someone who had been in a real gulag would disagree.  Anyway, regardless of your or my opinion about how enjoyable school is or was, the questioner needs to be aware that using "lifers" will make the school seem like a prison, and this may offend or put off a lot of people, depending on how it's used.  I'm not "anti-humour" but we need to be aware that the joke may be lost on someone and if they take it at face value it could have negative consequences for them.

Comment: @MaxWilliams, right, it depends on the context. _Lifer_ is black humor, and that might not be appropriate. As usual we are given very little context. If you thought that school was good, by the way, then that just means that they broke your mind, like they did to Winston Smith in 1984 ;)

Comment: @dangph "black humour" is the perfect term, thanks.  You're right about the lack of context too.   As it happens I have mixed feelings about my school years, but I'm still generally in favour of schools as a concept.

Comment: Perhaps "_same schoolers_" or "_single schoolers_" could be used to describe someone who's been at the same school all the time although, from a quick search, neither phrase seems to have been used this way previously.

Comment: At my school they were members of the 13-year club.

Comment: while *lifer* is a good thought, it has a wholly negative connotation.  It's not suitable here.

Comment: This is an interesting question.  It's like ... there's not really a word for someone who is "not an ex-pat".

Comment: Ah, that's an excellent idea @Riccati.  In the US, you could perhaps say "13-year students" to indicate they have been there every one of what the US calls "K-12" years.

Comment: I forgot to ask, is there not all the difference anywhere between "never attended a different school" and "always/only attended the same school"? The outcome is the same but isn't the process different?

Answer (score 1):

"Lifer" is the common term used at many K-12 private schools in Virginia. Based on a quick check of available yearbooks, I can confirm it has been in use since the 1970's. I'd really never thought of it having a negative connotation before reading some of the comments here. The kids are proud to be "lifers" and do not think it a disparaging term.

A quick search on the website of The Collegiate School in Richmond, Virginia yielded many examples, including this description of an alumna receiving an award:
"Cathy is a Collegiate lifer. Her daughters Carolyn ‘12, Frances ’14, and Julia ’17 are lifers as well." https://www.collegiate-va.org/page/news-detail?pk=824643

Answer (score 0):

tchrist's comment on "lifer" got me thinking, would "lifer student" work? Granted that wording seems to be very uncommon and would likely require further explanation, but I did Google it and surprisingly a result came up that describes the same kind of students in your post: http://www.nuevaschool.org/news/upper-school-news/1869-lifer-dinner-2017

Comment: "_Life student_" might be slightly more natural than "_lifer student_", although I'm not sure either would work without reasonable context.

Comment: When I hear “life/lifer student”, I think of someone who is continually learning new things and is actively seeking new information throughout their lives (regardless of schooling).

Comment: **It honestly doesn't work.**  it more suggests someone who (endlessly) does degrees, post graduate degrees, business degrees etc.  indeed, it's something like "lifetime learning".  (A political concept that was briefly popular in the US when unemployment was high.)

Answer (score 0):

> ...students at a K-12 school who have attended this same school the whole time from kindergarten through 12th grade...

Unfortunately there simply is not such a term.  (This is often the correct answer on SWRs; there's nothing wrong with a null result.)

Commentor @Riccati gave an excellent suggestion...

**"13-year students"**

I doubt we'll find something better.

> "Graduating this year we have 202 students, and I am proud to announce that 91 of them were 13-year students here at East High!  Go Wildcats!"

Answer (score 0):

original (Oxford)

ADJECTIVE

Present or existing from the beginning; first or earliest.

Edgar is one of our original students here at Woebegone Elementary School.

Comment: For me an 'original student' would be one who joined the school when it opened not, necessarily, one who spent all their school years there. Alternatively it might mean a student who exhibited original thought or great creativity.

Answer (score -2):

I believe the proper title for the students would be "alumni" for a group of students, alumnus which is defined as male and alumnae defined as a former female student.

Comment: (1) Calling students “alumni” *as they’re graduating* is a bit of a stretch (and calling them “alumni” ***before*** they graduate is just plain wrong). (2) This seems to miss the point of the question, which is to find a term that excludes students who transferred into this school from another.  “Alumni” would include transfer students, as long as they *graduated* from this school.